Sorry to interrupt - This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it
I have a screen flow that enables the user to create a contact and an account contact relationship at the same time.  It doesn't contain any custom LWCs, but it does utilize one Apex class.  I'm the last person who modified the flow, but I didn't receive an email for the error.  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue.  Is opening a case with Salesforce the best or only way to go?
Sorry to interrupt
This page has an error.  You might just need to refresh it.  First, would you give us some details?  Were reporting this as error ID: -1775489667

Technical Stuff:  connection was cancelled here


Please [edit] your post to include more details.  At what step in the flow does the error occur?  What specifically does the Apex class do?  Do previous versions work?

@DavidCheng fair point.  I'll update this tomorrow with more detail.  I spent time adding some flow-level logging to things, to see if I can capture where the failure is taking place in the flow.  No luck so far.

is the error in page load or when you try to use flow? what happens when you remove the flow. does it work? do you see anything in debug logs?

@PranayJaiswal it happens during execution of the flow.  The Lightning page loads fine.  I've enabled a user trace log with everything set to FINE and above to see if something is captured there.
